# Serial port forwarding in Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm having a problem with an old PC with Windows NT, 2000, 2003.

We use RDP to access to a Windows Server 2008 machine with a desktop application. The problem is that computer cannot see serial POS in that machine.

Do older versions of RDP allow serial port forwarding?